# React/Firebase. Why I can't delete element from my Firestore Database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I adding an item to the cart, it also gets into the database, but when I click on the delete button, the item is removed from the cart, but not from the database. What am I doing wrong?

This is a function that adds a product on click. (if necessary):

```
  const handleClick = async(item) => {
    const newItem = { ...item, id: v4() }
    await addDoc(collection(db, 'cart_products'), {
      id: newItem.id,
      image: newItem.image,
      name: newItem.name,
      priceTotal: newItem.priceTotal,
      category: newItem.category
    })
    setList([...list, newItem])
    console.log(newItem)
  }
```

This is a delete function:

```
    const deleteProduct = async(id) => {
        await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'cart_products', id))
        setList((list) => list.filter((product) => id !== product.id))
    }


    const products = list.map((product) => {
        return <CartItem product={product} key={product.id} deleteProduct={deleteProduct}/>
    })
```

This is a delete button

```
     <button className="btn bin" onClick={() => {deleteProduct(product.id)}}>
       <img src={bin} alt="bin" className='bin'/>
     </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `addDoc` method, which is used for generating it's own id for documents, while in the meantime you're generating your own *(different)* id on the client-side with `uuid.v4`

Just change your add (`handleClick`) method to, so your firestore `id` matches the one you're creating with your `uuid.v4` call.

```
setDoc(doc(db, 'cart_products', newItem.id), { 
 // ... data here
})
```

and it will work.

Alternatively you can just use the generated `id` from the `addDoc` method and take out the dependency on `uuid` entirely. (the `addDoc` call returns a `Promise<DocumentReference>` which contains the readonly property `id` you can access)

> Note: Your previous documents contain corrupted data (property `id` does not match the `document.id`), and will either need to be removed or fixed via a migration function